# Independence of random variables $X_1^2, X_2^2, \ldots, X_n^2$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

## Question

Let $X_1, X2, \ldots , X_n$ be random variables of independent same-distribution. In this case, $X_1^2, X_2^2, \ldots,  X_n^2$ can be said to be independent identical distributions?

Please let me know if you have a simple proof. I looked for references in Japanese books, but there were not many that were properly listed.

Comment: For positive $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, $$\mathbb{P}(X_1^2<x_1,\ldots , X_n^2<x_n)=\mathbb{P}(X_1<\sqrt{x_1},\ldots , X_n<\sqrt{x_n}).$$ Can you take it from there?

Comment: If the random variables $A$ and $B$ are independent of each other  then the random variables $f(A)$ and $g(B)$ are also independent of each other for any functions $f$ and $g$.  Meanwhile if $A$ and $B$ have the same distribution then $h(A)$ and $h(B)$ have the same distribution for any function $h$.

Comment: @jcneek That equation need not hold, e.g. if some of the $X_i$ are negative with positive probabillity.